# NativeScript: After installing firebase, simulator just shows white screen

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I installed NativeScript Vue and had things working well.  I'd make changes in my text editor and webpack would watch the changes, and restart the iOS simulator to reflect the changes.  I installed firebase this morning and all went seemingly well but now I don't see anything but a white screen after the initial splash screen.
There are no errors that I see and webpack still detects the change but I don't see anything:  here is what I see in my console:

```
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Running webpack for iOS...
Bundling application for entryPath ./main.js...
clean-webpack-plugin: /Development/muu/platforms/ios/muu/app/**/* has been removed.
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Development/muu/node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/backend.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Hash: fd69db530b6be0edb831
Version: webpack 4.35.0
Time: 10910ms
Built at: 06/29/2019 6:14:57 PM
                                                                                            Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                                                                      App_Resources/iOS/.DS_Store      6 KiB          [emitted]
                               App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json   1.84 KiB          [emitted]
                               App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-1024.png   57.1 KiB          [emitted]
                                 App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-29.png   1.64 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-29@2x.png   3.09 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-29@3x.png   4.36 KiB          [emitted]
                                 App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-40.png   2.29 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-40@2x.png   4.47 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-40@3x.png   6.41 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-60@2x.png   6.41 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-60@3x.png   9.15 KiB          [emitted]
                                 App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-76.png   4.25 KiB          [emitted]
                              App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-76@2x.png   8.69 KiB          [emitted]
                            App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-83.5@2x.png   9.74 KiB          [emitted]
                                                  App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/Contents.json   62 bytes          [emitted]
                          App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Contents.json   4.15 KiB          [emitted]
                      App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-1125h.png    160 KiB          [emitted]
                    App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-568h@2x.png   62.2 KiB          [emitted]
                    App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-667h@2x.png    112 KiB          [emitted]
                    App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-736h@3x.png    180 KiB          [emitted]
                App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape-X.png    165 KiB          [emitted]
                  App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape.png   60.9 KiB          [emitted]
               App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape@2x.png    187 KiB          [emitted]
               App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape@3x.png    198 KiB          [emitted]
                   App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait.png   59.5 KiB          [emitted]
                App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait@2x.png    182 KiB          [emitted]
                            App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default.png   20.3 KiB          [emitted]
                         App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default@2x.png   61.4 KiB          [emitted]
                 App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset/Contents.json  373 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset/LaunchScreen-AspectFill.png   1.67 KiB          [emitted]
App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset/LaunchScreen-AspectFill@2x.png    3.9 KiB          [emitted]
                     App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.Center.imageset/Contents.json  365 bytes          [emitted]
           App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.Center.imageset/LaunchScreen-Center.png   65.3 KiB          [emitted]
        App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.Center.imageset/LaunchScreen-Center@2x.png    202 KiB          [emitted]
                                                       App_Resources/iOS/GoogleService-Info.plist   1.16 KiB          [emitted]
                                                                     App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist   1.45 KiB          [emitted]
                                                        App_Resources/iOS/LaunchScreen.storyboard   3.84 KiB          [emitted]
                                                                 App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig  504 bytes          [emitted]
                                                               assets/images/NativeScript-Vue.png   8.22 KiB          [emitted]
                                                                                        bundle.js   20.2 KiB  bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                                                                     package.json  125 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                                       starter.js   39 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                                        vendor.js   2.43 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = vendor.js bundle.js
[./ sync ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$] . sync nonrecursive ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$ 175 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./ sync recursive (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$] . sync (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$ 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.scss] 334 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./main.js] 1.75 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 109 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./store.js] 142 bytes {bundle} [built]
    + 198 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
Preparing project...
Project successfully prepared (iOS)
Add iOS crash logging
Successfully transferred assets on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred images on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred NativeScript-Vue.png on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred bundle.js on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred package.json on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred starter.js on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
Restarting application on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.application on device 36355C74-4701-4B20-83FF-238858C33158.
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/bundle.js:395:14: 'firebase.init done'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> CreateElement(NativeFrame)'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> CreateElement(NativePage)'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> CreateElement(NativeActionBar)'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativepage), ElementNode(nativeactionbar))'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> CreateElement(nativegridlayout)'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativepage), ElementNode(nativegridlayout))'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:22410:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.22 | NSVue: 2.2.2)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativeframe), ElementNode(nativepage))'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am thoroughly confused as to what is going on since there are no errors.

Comment: The default configuration itself allows to watch for changes and update your app as needed, what sort of additional changes you made to webpack? I hope you are aware that you must do a clean build if you install new plugins those require native libraries such as Firebase.